# What is the meaning On<T> in a Generic Function

Tags: c#, generics

What is the meaning **On< T >** in a Generic Function

```
public IPlatformElementConfiguration<T, AbsoluteLayout> On<T>() where T : IConfigPlatform
    {
        return _platformConfigurationRegistry.Value.On<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`On` is the name of the Method, `T` is a generic type you define at runtime where `T` is of type `IConfigPlatform`

You should take a stroll through

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

> Generics were added to version 2.0 of the C# language and the common
>   language runtime (CLR). Generics introduce to the .NET Framework the
>   concept of type parameters, which make it possible to design classes
>   and methods that defer the specification of one or more types until
>   the class or method is declared and instantiated by client code. For
>   example, by using a generic type parameter T you can write a single
>   class that other client code can use without incurring the cost or
>   risk of runtime casts or boxing operations, as shown here:

**Example** of an extremely simple and completely useless generic method

```
public static void Method<T>(T input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T) + " : " + input);
}

public static void Main()
{
    Method("Hello");
    Method(234);
    Method(new DateTime());
}
```

**Output**

```
System.String : Hello
System.Int32 : 234
System.DateTime : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zeGFTs)

Answer (score 2):

`On` is the name of the method while `T` is the name you gave to a generic type that you'll use in your function.

As your function is generic, you don't know the type of objects that your method manipulates, so you have to declare some sort of alias for them. Most of the time, when you only use one generic type, you use `T`. Another convention is to use `TResult` for a generic return type.

Besides, there is also a constraint stating that the type `T` must be or inherit from `IConfigPlatform`.